# Datatable instant search textbox not showing

Tags: javascript, php

Search box missing on datatable, i used version 1.9.4 (datatable version).Here is my javascript code :

```
    $(function() {
        $('#search_result_table').dataTable({
            "bPaginate": true,
            "bLengthChange": false,
            "bFilter": true,
            "bSort": true,
            "bInfo": true,
            "bAutoWidth": false
        });
    });
```

Now I want to display the instant search text box.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle of your issue?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code, its working, there might be some other problem.

> Searchbox is in default configuration of DataTable you don't need to write any code for that.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable({
            "bPaginate": true,
            "bLengthChange": false,
            "bFilter": true,
            "bSort": true,
            "bInfo": true,
            "bAutoWidth": false
        });
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
   
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />


<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2009/01/12</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2012/03/29</td>
                <td>$433,060</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Donna Snider</td>
                <td>Customer Support</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>27</td>
                <td>2011/01/25</td>
                <td>$112,000</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```